# I want to trigger a single Javascript function when multiple images are done loading on the page. What will be the best way?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have multiple images on the page. And I want to trigger a function when all of them are completely loaded on the page. What is best way to accomplish this. Without using any third party plugin.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.onload`. This event fires when all content is loaded (including images).

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log('all images loaded');
};
```